# Insert file:// link into rich text field

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I've a XPages application where users can edit rich text fields.

Now I want to insert a link to a local file into this rich text field. I use the link action from the toolbar to insert the link `file:///c:\temp\readme.txt` The link is stored in the rich text field, but if I want to click on the link nothing happens neither in read mode nor in edit mode.
Standard http-links work as expected, only file links don't work.
HTML filtering is turned of i.e. set to `identy`

Does anybody has an idea how I can get file links to work within rich text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons the browser will not allow the file:// link on a HTTP/HTTPS page.